# If a ring has a unity $e$ and and for each elements $a$ in the ring has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$, does this ring have to be commutative?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

My guess is is this ring does not have to be commutative.
Since each elements $a$ has a unique multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$
and if I choose $b$ in this ring and $b \neq a^{-1}$ and base on the definition of the ring $ab$ does not have equal $ba$.
Am I right?

Comment: If 0 has a multiplicative inverse, then the ring is the degenerate zero ring $\{ 0 \}$ which is commutative.  I'm guessing that's probably not what you meant, though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring (giving the ring of quaternions as an example of a noncommutative ring where every nonzero element is a unit).